# Error response from daemon: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require ‘docker login

Tags: docker, dockerhub, docker-desktop

I have made a repository private in Dockerhub.
My repository name is 78124/webapp whch has an image with v1 tag

I have Docker Desktop 2.3.0.2 installed on Windows 10 machine
I do docker login and supply my dockerhub account credentials, I am able to login.

However when I try to pull my private dockerhub repository image with v1 tag using:

`docker pull 78124/webapp:v1`

I get following error:

```
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for 78124/webapp, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

I am unable to pull my own private repository.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you logged-in on command line as mentioned in error? You need to be logged-in